# Magento 2 - Get cart item qty change in Javascript

Tags: javascript, magento2, cart

I have a javascript file that loads when the page loads. This file defines two variables (one for the shopping cart items and one for the count).

This script also contains a `subscribe` that fires whenever the cart is updated.

When I add items to the cart, remove items from the cart or update the cart, this `subscribe` is hit and I am able to execute logic inside there.

This is fine for most however, when a user changes the qty of an item in the cart, I can never get the previous qty.

```
        var cart = customerData.get('cart');

        // Define variables to check against inside the subscribe
        var count = cart().summary_count;
        var currentItems = [...cart().items];

        // Watch the cart
        cart.subscribe(function () {
            // If the count has changed
            if (cart().summary_count !== count) {  
                    for(let i =0; i < cart().summary_count; i++){
                        var foundItem = currentItems.find(x => x.product_id == cart().items[i].product_id);
                        var currentItem = cart().items[i];

                        // Both of these values are the same
                        if(foundItem.qty < currentItem.qty){
                            var qtyChange = currentItem.qty - foundItem.qty;
                        }
                    }
            }

            // Set the count to the new value
            count = cart().summary_count;

            // Set the new currentItems array
            currentItems = cart().items;
        });
```

The `cart().summary_count` updates but the `qty` against the item updates in both the duplicated items array defined outside the `subscribe` as well as the `cart().items` array (which I'd expect).

I have noticed that the value for `qty` in the array defined outside the `subscribe` changes to a `string` and the `cart().items` version of the `qty` is an `int`.

Below is a screenshot of what I am seeing in dev tools. I have updated the qty in the cart for item_id 269

[image: screenshot of the two arrays]

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I may be wrong here, but I think the function inside the subscribe event supports 2 arguents that are the new and old value. Try to do a `console.log(arguments)` inside your function to check if this is the case.